# Online resource to study Russian language vocabulary

Tags: vocabulary, online-learning, russian

I'm looking for a website to study new Russian vocabulary.

Not any site teaches the right vocabulary for russian language. I speak Russian a little bit and a lot of sites tend to translate wrong. Does anyone know any site that offers a good Russian language information such as exercise and vocabulary
(because I'm afraid of studying a vocabulary that have a differnt meaning)?

Answer (score 8):

**Free**

- [Duolingo](https://www.duolingo.com/) is an immensely popular language learning platform, and they released their [Russian course for English speakers](https://www.duolingo.com/course/ru/en/Learn-Russian-Online) around 8 months ago. I have experience with Duolingo, and can attest to the quality of their courses *in general*, but I've not tried their Russian course. Usually, Duolingo courses focus more on vocabulary than grammar.
- [Memrise](http://www.memrise.com/) I also use frequently. The very nature of their learning system makes it ideal for learning vocabulary, so most of the courses there focus on vocab. Their list of Russian courses can be found [here](http://www.memrise.com/courses/english/russian/).

**Paid**

- [Babbel](https://www.babbel.com/) is another reasonably popular website for language learning, though it's not free as Duolingo is. Their Russian course can be found [here](https://www.babbel.com/learn-russian-online).
- [Rosetta Stone](http://www.rosettastone.com/) is another extremely popular language learning system, though it's rather pricey. [Rosetta Stone Russian](http://www.rosettastone.com/learn-russian)

These are just four resources I found, and I listed them because I've had at least *minimal* experience with the platforms before. Duolingo and Memrise I use all the time; Babbel, not so much, and Rosetta Stone, not at all (just seen it/heard of it, never used it).

If you need more resources, a Google search for "learn russian" should do the trick.

Comment: I've completed the Duolingo Russian course and it is pretty good, except that the quality falls off dramatically towards the end (poor English translataions and weird phrases.) It gave me enough vocab to have a conversation and was much more effective than any of my previous attempts to learn Russian.

Answer (score 4):

I made a monster post of [100 top resources to learn Russian](https://lingualift.com/blog/best-russian-learning-resources/) over at the LinguaLift Blog, categorized by type and proficiency level.

Comment: Welcome to Language Learning! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not specific to Russian, but I'm using [Quizlet](https://quizlet.com/) as a tool to learn Russian vocabulary.  In Quizlet, you can either use sets that others have prepared or you can make your own sets of question-answer (which in this case would be Russian-other), and then Quizlet has modes for Study, Learn, Test, as well as some games.